# External hard drive in windows 7 is not ejectable

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I used diskpart to create a new partition on an external USB hard drive, now the drive is no longer ejectable.

I formatted it as exFAT, on an MBR partition using the default byte/sector allocation.

It seems using diskpart or Disk Management in MMC wont allow me to make it as an "ejectable" drive.

How can I make it "ejectable" in windows for safe removal?

Comment: In device manager, check what is in the "Policies" tab for your drive. You might have issues if it is not set to "Optimize for quick removal"